# How to include library projects

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a working app and now wish to include an advertising system by [mopub](http://www.mopub.com/). Looking at their [getting started guide](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-client/wiki/GettingStarted) it says I should fist extract a "library project" (I'm not even sure what that is) using git. After having done that I now see that I have a directory called `mopub-android-sdk` inside this directory are a tree of further files and subdirectories.

The guide then states "Make sure the Android SDK files are in the same parent folder as your project"... this is where I'm confused. I have all my source files, androidmanifest etc in a directory `c:\android\mygame` am I now supposed to put `mopub-android-sdk` and all its sub-tree inside `c:\android`? or inside `c:\android\mygame`? (or somewhere else?)

**EDIT:** Some answers/comments have discussed the idea of converting the library project into a .jar file and then putting that in my libs directory... I have no objection to this so long as someone tells me there are no disadvantages to this compared to not making a jar - thinking about it more, wouldn't the jar have to include every single function, whereas if I left it as a library project, the compiler may be able to omit unused code?

**EDIT:** Now I am getting more sceptical about the make-jar-then-put-in-libs approach. I found `mopub-android-sdk.jar` in the `bin\res` directory and copied it to my projects libs directory. The ad system seemed to work fine, except in the location on screen where I expect to see a specific icon (to dismiss the full screen ad) there is a junk image. I noticed that amongst the tree of files beneath `mopub-android-sdk` there is a `res` directory containing png files. I suspect that these images are not in the jar file.

Comment: it should be on same `drive` i.e C:\. Not  necessarily be in same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're simply including a *.jar library, put it in the libs/ folder of your project.

If you're trying to include an entire project...

Right click the project you want it to be included into and go to properties. On the left side where there are tabs, select "Android". In the area that says "Library" press the "Add..." button and then select the project you want to include. Do a clean build of your project.

Answer (score 1):

Download the library to your host development system.

Create a new folder, libs, in your Eclipse/Android project.

Right-click libs and choose Import -> General -> File System, then Next, Browse in the filesystem to find the library's parent directory (i.e.: where you downloaded it to).

Click OK, then click the directory name (not the checkbox) in the left pane, then check the relevant JAR in the right pane. This puts the library into your project (physically).

Right-click on your project, choose Build Path -> Configure Build Path, then click the Libraries tab, then Add JARs..., navigate to your new JAR in the libs directory and add it. (This, incidentally, is the moment at which your new JAR is converted for use on Android.)

Comment: he is talking about `library projects` not about `libs`

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but isn't it easy enough to create a jar of the library project ?

Comment: YES! but then First he need to create `jar` from the `src` and then import it. :)